# Trapezoidal Rule to Find n

Tags: calculus

I just wanna confirm with someone whether this is right or not.

Q:

Use Trapezoidal Approximate to estimate$ ∫_1^3 \frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}dx $ with a maximum error of $ 10^{-3} $

A:

$$f''(x)=3e^{-3x}$$
$$[1,3]$$
$$|E_T|≤\frac{K(b-a^3)}{12n^2}$$
$$K=max⁡|f''(x)|=3e^{-3}$$
$$n^2≤\frac{K(b-a)^3}{12 E_T} $$
$$n≤\sqrt{\frac{3e^{-3} (2)^3}{(12)(10^{-3})}}$$
$$n≤9.978684118 $$
$$n≈10$$

Thanks

Comment: Hello, good evening and welcome. Your question needs a little more effort if you are to garner attention. Could you please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question and then https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to help format your text?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I just realized how bad the previous question was. I'll keep that in mind for future posts. It's edited now and I hope this one's better. Cheers.

Comment: That's a far better format, and you should get some comments now, given that you have shown your efforts too.

Comment: @SeanPaul: What is $f(x)$? What is the second derivative of that?

Comment: Oops sorry that was a typo. $f(x)=1/3 e^{-3x}$ and second derivative is $3e^{-3x}$

Comment: I agree with the calculation, but shouldn't that be $n \ge$?